# How to setup authorization code with PKCE flow in new spring-authorization-server to use my frontened app login screen

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2, pkce

In the new [spring-auhtozation-server](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server) is it possible to setup the authorization flow with PKCE, but to use my frontend app login screen instead of the spring default login screen and then to just continue the flow as it is?
I'm not able to find any kind of explanation or tutorial how to do that.
Does this even make sense to do in OAuth2 / OIDC standard?

Comment: Hi @Martel,  did you find how to specify using PKCE ?

Comment: Hi @Fozix, no, I did not.

In the end, we went with Keycloak. You can change Keycloak login page by your needs. Also, PKCE works fine there and that is what we needed.

Comment: Hi @Martel, for those intersted in implementing PKCE flow with spring authorization server, the solution is to define client authentification method =>                 .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE)
& remove the "secret" (no secret exchange in this flow)